# Vectorize parsing json list in python / pandas

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, vectorization

I am using python to get data from an API which returns a json which I need to parse for specific variables as below:

```
r=requests.get(request_here)
g=r.json()
N=len(g)
for i in range(0,N):
    Submission_Timestamp=g[i]['vars']['submission']['timestamp']
    Outcome=g[i]['appended']['suppressionlist']['add_item']['outcome']
```

Where each "i" is a unique record. While this method works I wanted to know if there is a way to vectorize this to grab everything in one swoop. Not all records will have the Outcome variable so I also need a KeyError exception for handling those records. Finally, I am pushing this into a pandas dataframe. How would I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Generic advice: if you are not going to use the index for anything other than accessing the elements, iterate *directly over the iterable...* so instead instead of using `for i in range(0, N)` use `for record in g: ...`

Comment: But, no, unless you are looking to write some C-extensions, you aren't going to be able to vectorize this, because you are iterating over a plain python `list`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I normally iterate over the iterable but in this case I thought I needed to pass an integer index into g[i]. What would my variable assignment look like if I did it as for record in g:?

Comment: Basically, everywhere that you have a `g[i]` change to `record`. Python for-loops are [foreach looops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop)

Comment: Can we see the json? And yes, you can import directly into pandas dataframe in *one swoop*.